# vue-cli3 public folder img doesn't show up

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

Does anyone know how to use the src attribute with an img file in a vue project's public folder? The browser is not finding the image.

I'm using Vue CLI 3.7.0

▼ folders

```
 |
 +-- src
 |    
 +-- public
       |  
       +-- favicon.ico
       +-- logo.png
       +-- index.html
```

I've tried something like `:src="xxx"`, but that didn't work.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img :src="'/favicon.ico'">
        <img :src="`${publicPath}favicon.ico`">
     </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by _"doesn't show up"_? Can you see the `<img>` element in your browser's _Elements_ console? If so, what is its `src` attribute value? If not, then it seems your component holding the images isn't being rendered

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can see `<img>` element in google chrome console panel. This is what it is. `<img data-v-7589ba10="" src="/img/logo.png">`

Comment: Ok, so where does `/img/logo.png` come from. The file `logo.png` doesn't appear anywhere in your question, nor does the `img` folder. For this to work, you would need to have the file in `public/img/logo.png`

Comment: sorry, I already added `logo.png` to public folder, and fixed img src parh. Element console is now `<img data-v-7589ba10="" src="/logo.png">` but img was broken.

Comment: _"was"_ broken? As in, it's not anymore?

Comment: I meant img show up in browser like this -> https://thewindowsclub-thewindowsclubco.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Broken-image-icon-in-Chrome.gif

Comment: Have you verified that the image is a valid PNG file? On Mac / Linux you can use `file path/to/logo.png` to verify the filetype.

Comment: I'm using windows10, and yes, filetype is `.png`. Vue.js logo.
I dont't know whether it is related to img file showing problem, `<img src="@xxx.png'>` doesn't work. It shows `Failed to compile.`

Comment: Nobody said to try `src="@xxx.png"` so not sure where that came from. Could you please upload a screenshot of your `public` directory and update the code in your question to be exactly the same as your code?

Comment: thanks. uploaded `test.jpg` code is `<img src="/test.jpg">`. It didn't work. Elements tab displays `<img data-v-7589ba10="" src="/test.jpg">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

From the comments below, it seems you're running

```sh
vue serve
```

Only a Vue CLI **project** knows about the `public` directory and `process.env.BASE_URL`. You need to run your **project** instead of using the [instant prototyping](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/prototyping.html#instant-prototyping) of `vue serve`.

In other words, run

```sh
npm run serve
```

See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#using-the-binary

---

If you have a file structure like this

```
├── public
│   ├── favicon.html
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo.png
```

then your code to display `logo.png` should look like

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="`${publicPath}logo.png`">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder

---

If you have your image in

```
├── public
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── logo.png
```

then your component template code becomes

```html
<img :src="`${publicPath}img/logo.png`">
```

Comment: thanks for detail answer.
file structure is as same as you written, i have img data in public/logo.png.
And added the same code, but img didn't show up..

Comment: @tanakahb have you tried restarting the dev-server, ie stop and run `npm run serve` again? Sometimes it won't pick up lots of moving files around.

Comment: Why are you using `vue serve`? That is literally for prototyping individual files ~ _"serve a .js or .vue file in development mode **with zero config**"_. _"Zero config"_ meaning it knows nothing about your `public` directory. Please use `npm run serve`

Answer (score 4):

Just use `<img src="/favicon.ico">`.

Comment: It works for me... :-)
Try to look at the generated code or at network requests, from which URL does it try to load `favicon.ico`.
Alternatively, put some `<a href="/favicon.ico">Link to favicon</a>` to your template. Where does it link, what URL?

Comment: thanks. link is this: http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico
Is this wrong URL?

Comment: That is correct URL. If your `index.html` is in the same folder (`public`), it simply must work.
Try another image (not `.ico`, simply `*.png` or `*.jpg`), put it in the same folder (`public`) and try to display.

Comment: yes, `index.htm` is in public/index.html. i added `logo.png` in public folder, tried `<img src="/logo.png">`  but img was broken.

Comment: Well, my last idea: 
1) I suppose you can display index html by visiting http://localhost:8080/index.html
2) You should be able to see `logo.png` by visiting http://localhost:8080/logo.png
3) If both is true, than the course must be that the component is not rendered, as @Phil suggested above.

Comment: thanks. localhost:8080/index.html isn't same as public/index.html! why...?

Comment: pasted localhost:8080/index.html source code.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vue CLI App</title>
  <link href="/app.js" rel="preload" as="script"></head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script></body>
</html>`

Comment: this is public/index.html source code. `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head><meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but test doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>`