# VueJS/Vue CLI - How to add a separate config for build

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Essentially, I want my build output to be a file that can be opened from the file system(without a web server), so I've set `publicPath: ''` in the `vue.config.js` file. But I don't want this when I'm running in development mode. How do I do this?

Edit: What I want is that `publicPath = ''` only when I run `vue build` it should stay the default when I run `vue serve`.

Comment: How to do this is specifically mentioned in the docs ~ https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

Comment: @Phil the default value is ```'/'```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```js
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/prodPath'
    : '/devPath'
```

and create a .env file on your directory with the declared var set to the current enivorment state:
`NODE_ENV='development'`

Comment: so with this, will ```publicPath = '/prodPath'``` when I run ```vue build``` and ```publicPath = '/devPath'``` when I run ```vue serve``` ? Sorry if the question wasn't clear, thats what i wanted to ask

Comment: You can `vue serve` and `vue build` for development and for production purposes. It will build or serve the app on the path you've declared on public path for each environment. So, answering your question: No. With the above vue build and serve will use the public path depending on the enviorment you've set, it does not depend on the command you are using.

Comment: is there a way to differentiate configs when running ```vue serve``` and ```vue build```?

Comment: @Guest1997 Don't run `vue serve`. I'm sure Yuri meant `npm run serve` (aka `vue-cli-service serve`)

Comment: I'm aware of the ```npm run serve``` command, but in this case I'm building a single component, which is why I'm using the ```vue serve``` command @Phil

Comment: @Guest1997 in that case, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56660466/283366